# Right align a field I have cast as a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to right align this field (cost) in sql server management studio for an export to a text file. I have formatted the this cost field to remove the decimal, which had four places and always displays at least 4 digits even if the number is simply 1.

```
cast(cost*1000 as decimal(10,0)) as cost
```

**Results:**

Original:

```
5.3300         
1.0000         
135.3600
```

New:

```
5330
1000
135360
```

Now I just need to right align my results and I'm not sure how to accomplish that. I am using sql server management studio express 2008. Any help with this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That is not something that you can do in a query.  Usually formatting is handled by the front end application.

However, in SSMS, if you want to see your query result in "Results to Text" mode, you can set a property to align your numeric data to right.

From Tools >> Options >> Query Results >> SQL Server >>:

1. Under General >> Default destination for results drop down list: Results to Text;
2. Under Results to Text >> Check **Right Align Numeric Values** and Output Format is: Column Aligned.  >> click OK and start a new query window to run your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
I had a numeric time column of 6, but needed to display in hh:mm:ss.
and resolved this way:

select 
substr(case
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 5 then '0'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 4 then '00'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 3 then '000'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 2 then '0000'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 1 then '000000'||char(Num6)
else
char(Num6)
end, 1,2)||':'||
substr(case
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 5 then '0'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 4 then '00'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 3 then '000'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 2 then '0000'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 1 then '000000'||char(Num6)
else
char(Num6)
end, 1,2)||':'||
substr(case
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 5 then '0'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 4 then '00'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 3 then '000'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 2 then '0000'||char(Num6)
when length(trim(char(Num6))) = 1 then '000000'||char(Num6)
else
char(Num6)
end, 5,2) as record_Time
from mytable;
```